# Upgrading Uchigatana +11

Tags: dark-souls

I am lvl 87 and trying to upgrade my from Uchigatana +10 to Uchigatana +11.
After checking the giant smith in anor londo and the smith in undead parish, none of them offered me to upgrade to 11. I am supposed to have titanite chunks. I have nine of them :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reinforce weapons to +11 and higher, you need to give the [Very Large Ember](http://darksoulswiki.wikispaces.com/Very+Large+Ember) to the blacksmith in the Undead Parish. It can be found in the New Londo Ruins after you've drained the water.